# PHP Sleep function using in yii controller action

Tags: php, yii

How to use sleep function in Yii controller after rendering a view file?

Here is the code, but not working.

```
public function actionThankyou()
{
    $saleep = false;

    $this->render('thankyou');

    $member_id = Yii::app()->user->getState('member_id');

    $saleep = true;

    if($saleep==true){
        sleep(8);       
        $this->loginToMemberAccount($member_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to sleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the function afterRender() as shown

```
 protected function afterRender($view, &$output)
   {
            //Your Sleep Code
   }
```

This method is invoked after the specified is rendered by calling render(). Note that this method is invoked BEFORE `processOutput()`. You may override this method to do some postprocessing for the view rendering.

Comment: but there are to many renders in this controller,how I call this function in specific render like after $this->render('thankyou');